# How to map OpenCL gpu memory to OpenCV matrix?

Tags: opencv, opencl

I calculated some matrixes on gpu with OpenCL, now I need to do some filtering on it using OpenCV. How can I do it with the least overhead?

```
cl::Buffer buffer;
cl::Kernel kernel;
kernel = cl::Kernel(program, "functionName", &err);
buffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size, NULL, &err);
kernel.setArg(0, buffer);
queue_IQ.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(size), cl::NullRange, NULL, NULL);

// Here, I would like to map the content of buffer to cv::Mat.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved like this with very little overhead:

1. Map the gpu memory to a pointer (in my case float*).
2. Use this pointer to create an opencv matrix. Note, opencv matrix constructor will not copy or allocate new memory for the pointer, instead it initializes the matrix head to point to the specified data (in this case on the gpu).

For example, if you are working with floats:

```
// cl::Buffer buffer
float* dataOnGPU = static_cast<float *>(queue_IQ.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, dataSize, NULL, NULL, NULL)); // map GPU memory to float*
cv::Mat dataInMat(height, width, CV_32F, dataOnGPU); // interface float* with cv::Mat

...

// Once done, you can unmap
queue_IQ.enqueueUnmapMemObject(buffer, dataOnGPU, NULL, NULL);
```

> For more info, see:
>
> - [enqueueMapBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html)
> - [enqueueUnmapMemObject](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueUnmapMemObject.html)
> - [cv::Mat constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9fa74fb14362d87cb183453d2441948f)

Comment: While the general question and answer are a bit short and could be elaborated, I think that this might be a reasonable question. If you elaborated the question, and added some further hints in the answer (e.g. mentioning or linking to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueUnmapMemObject.html ), I think I'd upvote them.

Comment: Did both, I think, let me know if you think more info is necessary.